# Pulling data via LEFT JOIN with multiple data per ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I have an issue where I am LEFT JOINING my Customer ID table to my taxexemption table and when I have multiple exemptions under the same customer, it just pulls the first system ID of data associated to that customer or no data at all. I have 3 pulling the same exemption, and 1 pulling no data at all except the customers name, the rest seem okay

[Exemption Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzh7.png)

[Tax Exemption MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aed5e.png)

[Customer List mySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt3O0.png)

This is the form page that lists all customers to be clicked on. I have the link to be clicked disabled for anyone without a specific user ID.

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>System ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Fuel Type</th>
        <th>Tax Type</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Expiration Date</th>
       
    </tr>

<?php
$IDUser = $_SESSION['userid']; 

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM TaxExemption LEFT JOIN CustomerList ON TaxExemption.CustomerID = CustomerList.ID ORDER BY Customer, FuelType ";

      $result = $conn->query($sql);


          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
        
        
        
        $customerid = $row['CustomerID']; 
       
       
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM customerlist WHERE ID = '$customerid' ";
       
             $result1 = $conn->query($sql);
       
       
                 if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
       
             while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
              
if($IDUser == '1' || $IDUser == '2' || $IDUser == '151' || $IDUser == '270') {echo "<td><a href='financefueltaxedit.php?ID=".$row['ID']."'>".$row1['Customer']."</a></td>"; }
              else
                {echo "<td>".$row1['Customer']."</td>";}
              
                 }}
       
        
       
  echo "     
        <td>".$row['FuelType']."</td>
        <td>".$row['TaxType']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Category']."</td>
        <td>".date_format(date_create($row['Expiration']),'m/d/Y')."</td></tr>
        
        
        ";

      } }



else{echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center' colspan='5'>Currently No Exemptions Added</td></tr>";}

?>

</table>

</div>
```

This is the edit page pulling in the info - which has issues if a customer has multiple exemptions as they all have different system ID's but same customer number

```
<div class="container">


    <h2>Customer Exemption Detail</h2>


    <ul>
      <li style='background: #324b81; color:white' id='profile'>Profile</li>
    </ul>

   <br><br>
   <p>Customer: <?php echo $row['Customer']?></p>
 

   

    <form class='updatecustomer'>

    <input name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" hidden="hidden">

    <table>


        <tr>
                <th>Customer ID:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name='CustomerID' value="<?php echo $row['CustomerID']?>" readonly disabled></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name='name' value="<?php echo $row['Customer']?>" readonly disabled></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
                <th>FuelType:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name='FuelType' value="<?php echo $row['FuelType']?>" readonly disabled></td>
        </tr>
        
         <tr>
                <th>TaxType:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name='TaxType' value="<?php echo $row['TaxType']?>" readonly disabled></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
                <th>Expiration:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name='Expiration' value="<?php echo $row['Expiration']?>"></td>
        </tr>
                
     
    
    </table>
    
    <br>

<input type="button" value="Update" id="update">
   
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='financefueltax.php';">


    </form>
    
<?php           }} ?>


</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#update').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

        var data = $('.updatecustomer').serialize();

            $.ajax ({             

                data:data,
                
                url:'processor-financefueltaxedit.php',
                
                type:'post'

            });

        
    function redirect(){  

        location.href='financefueltax.php';

      }

      

      setTimeout(redirect,500);



    });

    });
  

  $(document).ready(function(){


        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear(); 


    $('[name="statedate"], [name="feddate"], [name="Expiration"] ').datepicker({

        

        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: new Date(year - 1, month, day - 7),
        maxDate: new Date(year + 2, month, day)

        
      });


});

</script>
</body>
```

This is my processor page - which is allowing single exemption customers to correctly display - I only want the ability to change the date and post a new expiration date to taxexemptions table, I dont want other information to be edited hence the readonly fields - which is why I have an update statement only for the date.

```
<?php

require 'wconnectionfile.php';

$date = $_POST['date'];
$date = date_create($date);
$date = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");

$CustomerID = $_POST['CustomerID'];
$fueltype = $_POST['fueltype'];
$taxtype = $_POST['taxtype'];
$statetax = $_POST['statetax'];
$fedtax = $_POST['fedtax'];

if (!empty($date)) {
 
 if (!empty($fedtax)) {$taxtype = $fedtax; }  else {$taxtype = $statetax;}
 
$sql = "UPDATE taxexemption LEFT JOIN CustomerList ON TaxExemption.CustomerID = CustomerList.ID SET taxexemption.Expiration='$date' WHERE taxexemption.CustomerID='$CustomerID'";
 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    

}

 

} else {

    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

}



$conn->close();


?>
```

I am at a loss as to what to do for multiple exemptions, not to mention it doesnt post the updated date from the datepicker to the database

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple exemption problem, it is up to you or your client to decide what to do;  you can either:

- allow multiple tax exemption per client, and create an edit page for the tax exemptions relative to on client at once
- don't allow multiple tax exemptions, and for this you must delete duplicated tax exemptions per client

Comment: Wouldnt option A leave me in same boat, where id still have to figure out how to pull the different associated system ID's into the single client page, which if I could do it there, I could just do it on the list view of the exemptions?
I like the idea of listing out all exemptions under the client as a single page, but they want to see easily which ones are coming up to be expired which is why theirs that giant list view.

Comment: for the option A, the client page will contain a table of all his tax exemptions (ie system id's)

Comment: I ended up changing the primary key field of taxexemptions to ExemptionID since my issue was getting the row result to show $row['ID']; and both tables had a field called ID so it would pull the customerlist ID instead of the taxexemption ID; by changing the taxexemption ID to exemption ID I can then make the onclick the 'exemptionID' instead of 'ID' which kept pulling customerlist via the JOIN. - still messing with this, but I got it to display correctly... now to try posting the data